# Monitoring databases - VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

I would like to develop a Windows Service in VB.NET to monitor different SQL databases running in different servers.

The user will enter/define connection string for each database.
Also he/she will define connection interval.

For example, database A needs to be checked in every 5 mins and database B needs to be checked every 24 hours.

What is the best approach for this project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A Windows Service that has a while loop should suffice:

```
While (m_serviceIsStopping = False)

 For Each _server In _serverList
   If ServerNeedsToBeChecked(_server) Then
     CheckServer(_server)
   End If
 Next


 Thread.Sleep(100)
End While
```

The thread sleep is important to make sure the CPU doesn't get used up.

While some here may recommend to do so, DO NOT USE THE TIMER CLASS IN A SERVICE. They fail silently.

Also, I have written this kind of thing before and that's a very long interval if you are checking "up" or blocking status. Something like every minute or so would probably be a better indicator.